# Database.merge - error "Invalid field IsCustomerPortal for merge"

Tags: apex, error, database, merge, invalid

I'm trying to merge accounts in apex using database.merge - Getting error "Invalid field IsCustomerPortal for merge". This field is available in Account object.

The org do not have customer portal or community enabled. The org have "High Volume Customer Portal" licenses.

I would like to know if the database.merge have any restrictions with the fields when merging accounts.
The same code is working in another org where IsCustomerPortal field is not available.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you
Anand